# ASP.NET Identity customization and ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have existing User tables in my project, and existing code that I want to maintain for persisting users to my database. This is a new ASP.NET site, but it just needs to play nice with existing tables and objects.

In most of my previous developing efforts, I would simply use FormsAuthentication to handle the HTTP Authentication, use its static methods to set the cookies and redirect the browser, and customer prepare the roles on the Principle. While this has worked well for me in the past, I am worried that FormsAuthentication is headed for the same fate as Dodos, Newspapers, and Record Stores, and I am also trying to challenge myself to not avoid new technologies simply because they are new (-er.)

Also, my project is utilizing ADO.NET and not the Entity Framework, and I am hoping to not have to use EF just for the users.

Can anyone point to a tutorial or walkthrough that would help in my getting up to speed on the Identity process and customizing it to fit my needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at a project I have created for this topic on github https://github.com/giorgos07/AspNet.Identity.AdoNetProvider Hope you like it.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

> I am hoping to not have to use EF just for the users.

Identity uses Entity Framework Code First. You cannot get away with EF if you want to use Identity's auto-generated tables.

Adam Freeman *(author of Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 & 5)* offers [free 3 Chapters](http://www.apress.com/files/extra/ASP_NET_Identity_Chapters.pdf) just for Identity.

Comment: That's more than a little bit depressing for me, but on the other hand that link you posted looks like it will be extremely helpful for me to better understand the Identity framework in general. Thanks!

Comment: Does that mean that identity framework can be used without entity framework if we do not want auto generated tables?